# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - OpenJDK 11: GTK theme for Java app

Tags: java, themes, fonts, gtk, arduino

I am modifying the Arduino Snap because it looks ugly. I want the same GTK font and look like the rest of the applications in Ubuntu; light gray instead of orange for focused item menu.

[image: https://i.ibb.co/WBHLxnn/Schermata-del-2021-05-26-10-29-43.png]

The `JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable is not working, though.

I tried with:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true \
-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel \
-Dswing.crossplatformlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel"
```

But received this message:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by processing.app.linux.GTKLookAndFeelFixer
         (file:/snap/arduino/56/lib/arduino-core.jar) to field
         com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel.styleFactory
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of
         processing.app.linux.GTKLookAndFeelFixer
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal
         reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

How can I fix this?